# how to Insert table from another tables

Tags: mysql

i have two table, art and art_tag_art.
this is column art table :

```
id
title
slug
image
```

this value art table
[image]

this is column art_tag_art

```
id
art_id
tag_id
```

value art_tag_art
[image]

i want to copy all art.id to art_tag_art.art_id and at the same time copy all art_tag_art.tag_id(which has existed) in new row.

I have tried and searching several mysql syntax insert into and select :

```
select id into @aid from art;
select tag_id into @tid from art_tag_art;
insert into art_tag_art (art_id, tag_id) values (@aid,@tid);


INSERT INTO art_tag_art (art_id, tag_id) 
SELECT art.id, art_tag_art.tag_id 
FROM art, art_tag_art order by id;
```

but nothing works. This time I get an error message : `Error Code: 1364. Field 'id' doesn't have a default value`

Expected value :
[image]

Comment: Is your Id a auto increment field ??

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande, yes it is.

Comment: Can you put some dummy data to it. So it will be easy to understand what you exactly trying to do

Comment: One thing I will point out, your second insert statement will not work because of the ambiguous field in the order by.

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande : ok, i've updated post.

Comment: @RMT : i've tried without order, value tag_id in new line is not what i expected

Comment: On what basis are the new line tag_ids being allocated?

Comment: @P.Salmon : in fact, the tag_ids value based on another tables, but I have to copy some rows because the value are still the same

Comment: Best show the other tables since there is now way of deriving them from your sample here.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

`select id=@aid from art order by id;
select tag_id=@tid from art_tag_art;
insert into art_tag_art (art_id, tag_id) values (@aid,@tid);

INSERT INTO art_tag_art (art_id, tag_id) 
SELECT art.id, art_tag_art.tag_id 
FROM art, art_tag_art order by id;`

Comment: thank you sir, i've tried but value tag_id in new line is not what i expected.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this but it doesn't look all that sensible

```
insert into art_tag_art(art_id,tag_id)
select a.id ,(select at.tag_id from art_tag_art at where at.id = a.id - 25) 
from art a;
```